# Create a lists of categories and their subcatgory in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have three tables as category, subcategory and subcategory_category that I use to store the foreign key of other table in

I want to show a list with category and subcategory, such as:

- category1

  - subcategory1
  - subcategory2
- category2

  - subcategory3
  - subcategory4

I tried this but it is not OK

in my controller:

```
$mycategories = SubcategoriesCategories::with('parent')->with('children2')->get();
```

and in model:

```
class SubcategoriesCategories extends Model  {
    protected $table = 'subcategories_to_categories';
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\categories', 'categories_id');
    }

    public function children2()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\subcategories', 'subcategories_id');
    }
}
```

in mysubcategories_categories table i have:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For children operations you can use nested set technique, there is a library that can help you, it is called Baum https://github.com/etrepat/baum

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't configure your modeles right..

its should be like:

```
class Category{
   public function subcategories(){
    return $this->hasMany('app\subcategory')//or whatever is your relations
   }
}
```

and than in controller:

```
$categories = Category::with('subcategories')->all();
```

Comment: i have three table and i want to use subcategories_catgories  table

Comment: each subcategory have also subcategory?

Comment: what do u mean?each category has subcategory

Comment: so I cant understand you.. you have parent and child, to get the child from parent decalre the relation

Comment: can you edit your post and give us the fields for each table?

Comment: so you want many to many, read about it here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many